# setTestProviderLocation does not trigger onLocationChanged in the service test case

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps

I have small service implementing LocationListener. I tested it manually with my application and it works properly.
I wrote also a test case for the service.
I used setTestProviderLocation expecting that service will receive location update. 
However, it does not happen.
Does anybody know what's a problem? I'd like to emphasize that the same service works in real application.
Test case is added below

```
 package com.gkatz.android.mtg.test;

 import java.util.List;

import com.gkatz.android.mtg.LocationService;
import com.gkatz.android.mtg.LocationService.LocationBinder;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.test.ServiceTestCase;

public class LocationServiceTest extends ServiceTestCase<LocationService> implements LocationListener{

public LocationServiceTest() {
    super(LocationService.class);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setUp();
}

public void testBinding(){
    IBinder locationBinder;

    locationBinder = getServiceBinder();
    assertNotNull(locationBinder);
}

public void testStart(){
    Intent locationIntent = new Intent(getContext(), LocationService.class);

    startService(locationIntent);
}

public void testNoStart(){
    LocationService locationService = getService();
    assertNull(locationService);
}

public void testLocationUpdate() throws InterruptedException{

    LocationBinder locationBinder;
    LocationService locationService;
    Context context = getContext();

    LocationManager lm = getLocationManager();

    context.registerReceiver(locationReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("android.mtg.custom.intent.action.GPS_LOCATION"));

    locationBinder = (LocationBinder)getServiceBinder();
    assertNotNull(locationBinder);

    locationService = getService();
    assertNotNull(locationService);

    Location loc = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    loc.setLongitude(4.890935);
    loc.setLatitude(52.373801);
    loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

    lm.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, loc);

    SystemClock.sleep(3000);

    loc.setLongitude(35.2276757);
    loc.setLatitude(31.7765488);
    loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

    lm.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, loc);

    synchronized (this) {
        this.wait(2000);
    }

    Location lastLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    System.out.println("Last known longitude: " + Double.toString(lastLoc.getLongitude()) +
                       "Last known latitude: " + Double.toString(lastLoc.getLatitude()));
    assertEquals(35.2276757, locationService.getLongitude());
    assertEquals(31.7765488, locationService.getLatitude());

    context.unregisterReceiver(locationReceiver);
    lm.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
private BroadcastReceiver locationReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        assertTrue(intent.getAction().equals("android.mtg.custom.intent.action.GPS_LOCATION"));
        System.out.println("Action received: " + intent.getAction());
        this.notify();
    }
};

private IBinder getServiceBinder(){
    Intent locationIntent = new Intent(getContext(), LocationService.class);
    return bindService(locationIntent);
}

private LocationManager getLocationManager(){
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)
    getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    lm.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                       true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
                       Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

    lm.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
    LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);
    return lm;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("LocationServiceTest, onLocationChanged, lon:" +
            Double.toString(location.getLongitude()) + ", lat:" +
            Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: @gk: Actually i am having same requirement for writing the testcases for GPS.Can u plz let me know is that working or else i have to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates`
`lm.requestLocationUpdates("YOUR PROVIDER", 0, 0, YOUR_LOCATION_LISTENER);`

Found at [Location guide of Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)